# Double the records in the database using MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

How do I double or triple the rows (duplication also fine) in an existing table using mysql?

Comment: Second question in a row against basic DB design rules. **stacloverflow indeed becoming a source of BAD practices**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick, if you have no PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE indexes.

```
INSERT INTO table SELECT * FROM table;
```

If you do have such indexes, simply list all the columns in the table that do not have these indexes. E.g. if `colA` has a UNIQUE or PRIMARY KEY index:

```
INSERT INTO table (colB, colC) SELECT colB, colC FROM table;
```

Note that this will only work if your ID column (colA) has the AUTO_INCREMENT property set (this is usually the case for integer ID columns). If not then you are out of luck. In that case you cannot use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` to duplicate rows because you need to supply the unique indexes manually.

Answer (score 1):

In words,
use select to get everything, than use insert....

Comment: can u give me the example for this

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO table (SELECT * FROM table)
```

You have to exclude the primary key.

```
INSERT INTO table (col1, col2) SELECT col1, col2 FROM table;
```

Do not select primary key.

You have to mention all the fields excluding primary key. I believe you have an auto-increment column do not mention that column in above command but include all other columns.

Comment: @user655334: if there is a UNIQUE KEY (or PRIMARY KEY), the row cannot exist two times. What do you want to happen in that case? Try `INSERT INTO table (SELECT * FROM table)`

Comment: @user: you have to exclude primary key from the select

Comment: @shakti: u mean remove the primary key and insert?

Comment: @user NO, check the updated answer do not mention the primary key in command

Comment: @user: Yes you have to mention all 20 fields here unfortunately no shortcut here

Comment: @shakti: got it. i dump the table as '.sql' and copy the insert statement in that file. Anyway, thanks once again

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't do that.
Keep your tables in Normal form that means no duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Col. Shrapnel: **you should not do this**.

Sander got it right:

- if you want to do this, `INSERT INTO
  table SELECT * FROM table` is the way
  to go
- If there is a PRIMARY AUTOINCREMENT key, `insert into table (all-but-key) select all-but-key from table`
- If there are other UNIQUE keys, you can't do this.

Another dirty workaround:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE UNION ALL SELECT * FROM TABLE
```

You could put this in a VIEW or a merge table...

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to duplicate all rows in the same table:

```
INSERT INTO yourtable()
SELECT * FROM yourtable;
```

This ofc only works if you don't have any unique keys on the table.